# C++ Conditional Operator versus if-else

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, operator-keyword, if-statement

I have always wondered about this. Let's say we have a variable, string weight, and an input variable, int mode, which can be 1 or 0.

Is there a clear benefit to using:

```
weight = (mode == 1) ? "mode:1" : "mode:0";
```

over

```
if(mode == 1)
    weight = "mode:1";
else
    weight = "mode:0";
```

beyond code readability? Are speeds at all affected, is this handled differently by the compiler (such as the ability of certain switch statements to be converted to jump tables)?

Comment: check this out by `gcc -s` output for each of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key difference between the conditional operator and an if/else block is that the conditional operator is an expression, rather than a statement.  Thus, there are few places you can use the conditional operator where you can't use an if/else.  For example, initialization of constant objects, like so:

```
const double biasFactor = (x < 5) ? 2.5 : 6.432;
```

If you used if/else in this case, `biasFactor` would have to be non-const.

Additonally, constructor initializer lists call for expressions rather than statements as well:

```
X::X()
  : myData(x > 5 ? 0xCAFEBABE : OxDEADBEEF)
{
}
```

In this case, myData may not have any assignment operator or non-const member functions defined--its constructor may be the only way to pass any parameters to it.

Also, note that any expression can be turned into a statement by adding a semicolon at the end--the reverse is not true.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is purely about presenting the code to a human reader. I'd expect any compiler to generate identical code for these.

Comment: that's not true, you can't use an if/else to assign values to a variable in a single expression, which is important not because of the resulting asm code, but the way high-level part of the language works, like with constants, constructor inits, and static function variables, etc. Some might argue that since the instruction count is the same for a = (w == x ? y : z) than it is for if (w==x) a=y; else a=z; which may be true and for simplistic expressions after optimization it may be so. however, it was not intended to be used in the simplistic fashion but to facilitate the previously mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

With mingw, the assembly code generated with

```
const char *  testFunc()
{
    int mode=1;
    const char * weight = (mode == 1)? "mode:1" : "mode:0";
    return weight;
}
```

is:

```
testFunc():
0040138c:   push %ebp
0040138d:   mov %esp,%ebp
0040138f:   sub $0x10,%esp
10          int mode=1;
00401392:   movl $0x1,-0x4(%ebp)
11          const char * weight = (mode == 1)? "mode:1" : "mode:0";
00401399:   cmpl $0x1,-0x4(%ebp)
0040139d:   jne 0x4013a6 <testFunc()+26>
0040139f:   mov $0x403064,%eax
004013a4:   jmp 0x4013ab <testFunc()+31>
004013a6:   mov $0x40306b,%eax
004013ab:   mov %eax,-0x8(%ebp)
12          return weight;
004013ae:   mov -0x8(%ebp),%eax
13        }
```

And with

```
const char *  testFunc()
{
    const char * weight;
    int mode=1;
    if(mode == 1)
        weight = "mode:1";
    else
        weight = "mode:0";

    return weight;
}
```

is:

```
testFunc():
0040138c:   push %ebp
0040138d:   mov %esp,%ebp
0040138f:   sub $0x10,%esp
11          int mode=1;
00401392:   movl $0x1,-0x8(%ebp)
12          if(mode == 1)
00401399:   cmpl $0x1,-0x8(%ebp)
0040139d:   jne 0x4013a8 <testFunc()+28>
13              weight = "mode:1";
0040139f:   movl $0x403064,-0x4(%ebp)
004013a6:   jmp 0x4013af <testFunc()+35>
15              weight = "mode:0";
004013a8:   movl $0x40306b,-0x4(%ebp)
17          return weight;
004013af:   mov -0x4(%ebp),%eax
18        }
```

Pretty much the same code is generated. The performance of your application shouldn't depend on small details like this one.

So, no it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It looks like you've compiled without optimization (frame is still present, variables are not inside registers). Even if the unoptimized code would differ it really matters if optimized one do. (As of performance - it depends on application. In most application it does not but in some optimizing innermost loop to perform ns faster can translate into real money).

Comment: In regards to performance based solely on something this small, you're right. However, I ask as picking up many small performance increases can lead to a larger one.

Comment: @CollinBiedenkapp: I'm willing to say that in this will result in identical code. My bent is slightly towards HPC and drivers and there small improvements in inner loop can make computation run say days quicker - however in such cases you think first about algorithm (here's the place where 99% of cases should stop), then about architecture optimization (cache efficiency etc.) and at the end instruction scheduling. Compilers have reverse - the last one can be done efficiently by them (use `-Ox` etc.) and there is research/beta implementation of the architecture optimization.

Comment: (continued) That said - I have no idea how to reason efficiently about superscalar out-of-order architectures (and compilers are much better at it then me) - which are used by most processors - and I'd be completely lost if you throw multithreaded processor (i.e. hypherthreading). Before you do anything check if a) is speed good enough (does improvement justify the cost) b) what's your bottleneck in code c) what is cause of bottleneck (memory, cpu, ...) d) what is the highest level you can put optimization in.